How to prove the action of a group on a set of its Sylow p subgroups faithful in these cases (and why?)?
Firstly, I was learning material that included this.
Let $S$ be the set of Sylow 5 subgroups of $S_5$. Then, we can consider the action of $S_5$ on $S$ by conjugation. From this we get the associated map $\varphi: S_5 \to S({S}) \cong S_6$. This I understand, however I get confused in the argument that this map is injective. It states that if $\sigma$ is in the kernel of the group action (and thus of the homomorphism), we have that $$\sigma P \sigma^{-1} = P \ \forall P \in S$$ Since we know that each $P \in S$ is generated by a 5 cycle, let some $P = \langle (a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5) \rangle$. Then $$\sigma (a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5) \sigma^{-1} = ( (\sigma(a_1)\sigma(a_2)\sigma(a_3)\sigma(a_4)\sigma(a_5))) \in P$$ This makes sense to me, however it then states that this is only true if and only if $\sigma \in P$ and since then $\sigma \in P \ \forall P \in S$, we must have that $\sigma$ is the identity in $S_5$. I do not understand this part. Why must $\sigma \in P$ if $\sigma P \sigma^{-1} = P$? Given this fact I understand why $\sigma$ must be the identity, however.
Then later I ran into a problem where I once again was confused on the same part. Let $G$ be a group of order 24, where none of its Sylow subgroups are normal. So $G$ has 3 Sylow 2 subgroups and 4 Sylow 3 subgroups. Then we can define a group action of $G$ on $S$ the set of Sylow 3 subgroups by conjugation. With this we get the associated homomorphism $\phi: G \to S({S}) \cong S_4$. This all makes sense, but then it states that this action is faithful, how? Once again, it is clear that if $x$ is in the kernel of the group action, we have that $xPx^{-1} = P \ \forall P \in S$, but I have a hard time following how this implies that $x$ is then trivial.
Any critique or further reading on the topic would be greatly appreciated

The reason you are confused is that you are over-reading what the statements say.
To say that the action is faithful is to say that the map $\varphi$ is injective. This is equivalent to saying that if $\sigma\in S_5$ is such that for every $5$-Sylow subgroup $Q$ we have $\sigma Q\sigma^{-1}=Q$, then $\sigma=e$. Note that this must hold for every $5$-Sylow subgroup, not just for one.
So it is not enough that $\sigma (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)\sigma^{-1}\in P$; this is necessary, but is not sufficient. And the claim isn't that if $\sigma$ normalizes $P$ then it is the identity (that's never true, since $P$ normalizes itself); it is that if $\sigma$ normalizes every $5$-Sylow subgroup then it is the identity.
In this case we know it works because the only possible kernels for $\varphi$ are $\{e\}$, $A_5$, and $S_5$, and since the action is certainly transitive by the Sylow Theorems, then the image must have order at least $6$, and so the kernel must be $\{e\}$.
For the second part, see the discussion here.

There are $6$ $5$-Sylow subgroups so the image must have order at least $6$, not $5$.

@RobertShore Yes, thanks.

The first statement is not true.  Let $P= \langle 1~2~3~4~5 \rangle = \langle g \rangle$ and let $\sigma = (2~3~5~4)$.  Then $\sigma g \sigma^{-1} = g^2 \in P$, but $\sigma \notin P$.  More generally, the size of the orbit of $P$ under this action is the index of its stabilizer.  The stabilizer of $P$ under this action is $N_{S_5}(P)$, so that normalizer has index $6$ and therefore order $20$, so it must contain elements that are not in $P$.
The way to show that $\varphi$ is injective is simply to note that the only non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_5$ is $A_5$, and since $[S_5:\ker \varphi] \gt 2$ and $\ker \varphi \lhd S_5$, it must be the case that $\ker \varphi = \{e \}$.
